# Any Suggested Maintenance for Cloned Mac OS X Boot Disk

Tags: mac, maintenance

I've cloned my MacBook Pro's internal drive to a larger, faster hard drive, using Carbon Copy Cloner.

The new drive is installed and seems to be working fine.  Is there anything I should do to "clean up" anything that may have been screwed up or left behind by the cloning process?

FWIW, Spotlight has re-indexed the drive, and I plan to use Disk Utility to analyze the drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cloning process succeeded, you can boot from the new drive, and Spotlight (and Time Machine if you're using it) work fine, there should be nothing that you need to clean up from the process.

Screw ups in a copy will either be catastrophic and you'd notice immediately, or minor (like corruption of a document) that you won't notice unless you open and verify just about every file on the hard drive.

If you've used the new drive for a couple of days and the system isn't acting strangely, I'd say you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If it ain't broke don't fix it.